# Contacts Not Loading in Empathy [Ububtu 14.04]

Tags: 14.04, empathy, contacts

I just installed empathy, and i attach my facebook account and my gmail account.
But the contacts of gmail accounts are not loading. Following the screensheet of empathy.

[image]

I killed empathy by running,

```
ps -aef | grep empathy
```

and

```
kill -9 processId
```

then restarted but contacts are not loading.

But when i tried with my facebook account, the contacts are loading properly.

The contact screen shows below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a google-specific matter regarding contacts. On an up to date Ubuntu 14.04 I can't access any google contacts. My google-calendar however integrates just fine. So may be this is a bug.